# Bool returns true whereas one of the excel cell value does not matches to other cell value using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

I compared 1st worksheet of workbook1 to 1st worksheet of wrokook2 and then after comparing data of first worksheet go to second work sheet. Compare second worksheet of workbook1 to the second worksheet of workbook2. Here is image
[image]

The code I used is

```
public bool CompareFiles(string filePath1, string filePath2)
        {

            bool result = false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            
            //Open files to compare
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath2);
          
            int numSheets = workbook2.Sheets.Count;

            for (int a = 1; a <= numSheets; a++)
            {
                //Open sheets to grab values from
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook1.Sheets[a]; 
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook2.Sheets[a]; 

                //Get the used range of cells
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet2.UsedRange;
                int maxColumns = range.Columns.Count;
                int maxRows = range.Rows.Count;

                //Check that each cell matches
                for (int i = 1; i <= maxColumns; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= maxRows; j++)
                    {
                        var value = range.Cells[maxRows, maxColumns].Value2;
                        if (worksheet1.Cells[j, i].value== worksheet2.Cells[j, i].value)
                        {

                            result = true;
                        }
                        else
                        
                            result = false;
                    }
                    
                }

                
            }

            workbook1.Close();
            workbook2.Close();
            excel.Quit();

            return result;
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(CompareFiles(filepath1 , filepath2);
```

now consider the screenshot
[image]
The value of cell B5 doesnot match in both workbooks. The bool should return false. Where as it is returning true and asset is showing `is true` passing the testcase. Whereas it should get failed. It fails the test case only if the last cell value differs. Otherwise it will pass the testcase.

How can I resolve this issue? I am using C#.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably comparing object references (I assume, that worksheet2.Cells[j, i].value is an object). Please, try cast it to string

```
if ((string)worksheet1.Cells[j, i].value== (string)worksheet2.Cells[j, i].value)
```

Comment: It is showing 'Cannot convert type 'double' to 'string''

Comment: That's because in column 3 you have numbers.

Comment: Still it is passing the testcase where as the value differs in cell.

Answer (score 0):

Should you convert your var to string and use string.Compare? I would suggest debugging that specific row as to how it is read.